# SOAP UI tool not allowing any html tags in string input for WCF method

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui, soap-client

How to allow  tags as input string from SOAP UI tool into my WCFservice method?
Kindly advice.

Comment: Have you tried to click Form  button, you could directly  input your parameter(even the content contains html tag) and avoid directly operate xml. Or you could use class that could encode html tag.For example, you could use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

Answer (score 1):

HTML is kind of XML and SoapUI will not understand it as the soap BODY will deviate from the data contract specified on the service.

Hence, you will have to use **CDATA** for sending any XML data as parameter.

Refer [this article](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html) for details.

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
           xmlns:sam="http://www.example.org/sample/">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <sam:searchResponse>
                 <sam:searchResponse>
                    <item><id>1234</id><description>
        <![CDATA[
<item><width>123</width><height>345</height>
    <length>098</length><isle>A34</isle></item>

    ]]>
        </description><price>123</price>
                    </item>
                 </sam:searchResponse>
              </sam:searchResponse>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```